# PyGears qrange gear - ValueError: [0], too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, pygears

Below is the code in PyGears, the idea is to have DUT that will convert Array into Queue, but **dut** gear is dropping an error " VelueError too many values". As far as I understand **qrange** should output DTI which has Queue type for data. I tried to unpack this Queue on Data and EOT but I keep getting this error.

> for i, last in qrange(len(din.dtype)): ValueError: [0], too many
> values to unpack (expected 2), in the module "/dut"

```
from pygears import gear
from pygears.typing import Uint, bitw, Queue, Array
from pygears.lib import qrange, drv
from pygears.sim import sim


@gear
async def dut(din: Array) -> Queue['din[0]']:
   i = Uint[bitw(len(din.dtype) - 1)](0)

   async with din as val:
       print(len(din.dtype))
       for i, last in qrange(len(din.dtype)):
           print(i)
           print(last)
           yield val[i], last

@gear
async def check(dut_res, *, ref):
   for ref_transaction in ref:
       for element in ref_transaction:
           async with dut_res as (data, eot):
               assert element == data

seq=[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80]]
drv(t=Array[Uint[8], 8], seq=seq) \
   | dut \
   | check(ref=seq)

sim()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

- Queue input data can be accessed by using either **async with** or **async for**
- **Async for** unpacks the **Queue interface** into **data** and **EOT** variables
- Reading is done by raising **ready** signal and blocking execution until **valid** is set
- After the loop body is executed, **EOT** is checked for loop termination

Therefore adding simple **async** before **for** in loop solved the problem for me.

```
@gear
async def dut(din: Array) -> Queue['din[0]']:
   i = Uint[bitw(len(din.dtype) - 1)](0)

   async with din as val:
       async for i, last in qrange(len(din.dtype)):
           yield val[i], last
```

Answer (score 0):

i cannot find the documentation for this `qrange`, but what does it return? is it like `range` and returns a sequence of numbers? This would explain the Error:

The line `for i, last in qrange(len(din.dtype)):` expects, that `qrange` returns a sequence of two element sequences. this would raise the ValueError.

`i,last` unpacks a sequence of 2 elements in the variables `i` and `last` - typically one uses this pattern with an iterator yielding pairs, like `enumerate`: `for i,element in enumerate(some_sequence):`